# How can i remove HTML Tags from String by REGEX?

Tags: c#, regex

I am fetching data from Mysql but the issue is "HTML tags i.e.

```
&lt;p&gt;LARGE&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Lamb;<br>;li;ul;&nbsp;
```

also being fetched with my data i just need "LARGE" and "Lamb" from above line. How can I separate/remove HTML tags from String?

Comment: How have you tried to do it?

Comment: Given that the html is invalid by virtual of being partially encoded, you really really REALLY don't want to try to come up with a regex that can handle this. Regexes to manipulate html are bad enough. Regexes that can manipulate BROKEN html are beyond the purvey of even gods like Alan Turing.

Comment: Good luck. Your source data is screwed. Start again.

Comment: Parse the HTML source and then navigate through the resulting tag hierarchy and get the content of tags instead of trying to use regex (which won't work). Google Html Agility Pack.

Comment: @xxbbcc, mybirthname: there is no html there.

Comment: yeah you're in bad shape, I'd try to do a replace on as many as possible to salvage anything and start again. `string.Replace("&lt","").Replace("p&gt","").Replace("<br>","").Replace("li","").Replace("ul","").Replace("&nbsp","").Replace(";","");`

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm sorry, what do you mean? If his input data contains HTML fragments, then parsing it will build a tree that can be navigated. The rest is text content.

Comment: @xxbbcc `&lt;p&gt;` is no html, or not something that will build up to a DOM. It will become the literal text `<p>`, without any meaning semantic to html.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm very much aware of that but it doesn't change the correctness of my comment. He does have `<br>` in his sample (the rest is who-knows-where-from); everything else is text content (as he'll realize soon). Using regex is a no-go.

Comment: @xxbbcc an html parser will return the **text** `<p>LARGE</p><p>Lamb;<br>;li;ul;`. No parser or xpath query will remove what OP calls "HTML tags" from that string, because as far as the parser is concerned, that _is_ the content, not html tags (apart from the `<br />` perhaps).

Comment: @CodeCaster You are correct, but Html parser read it pretty nice.

Comment: @mybirthname yeah, if you, and I quote, "assume that you fix your html elements".

Comment: @CodeCaster As I said, I'm aware of that - I didn't mis-read his sample. However, even there, he has `<br>` so the sample would be parsed into several nodes as it is. If he properly decodes the HTML before parsing, it becomes similar input with more HTML nodes in it.

Comment: For the OP's reference, here's why you cannot use regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/682404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try this

```
// erase html tags from a string
public static string StripHtml(string target)
{
//Regular expression for html tags
Regex StripHTMLExpression = new Regex("<\\S[^><]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |   RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);

return StripHTMLExpression.Replace(target, string.Empty);
}
```

> call

```
string htmlString="<div><span>hello world!</span></div>";
string strippedString=StripHtml(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that the HTML is intact, perhaps something like the following:

```
<ul><li><p>LARGE</p><p>Lamb<br></li></ul>&nbsp;
```

In which case, I would use HtmlAgilityPack to get the content without having to resort to regex.

```
var html = "<ul><li><p>LARGE</p><p>Lamb</p><br></li></ul>&nbsp;";
var hap = new HtmlDocument();
hap.LoadHtml(html);

string text = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(hap.DocumentNode.InnerText);
// text is now "LARGELamb "

string[] lines = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")
    .Select(h => HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(h.InnerText)).ToArray();
// lines is { "LARGE", "Lamb", " " }
```

Comment: but Mitch its can't remove span tag like i have <span style=line-height: 1.6em;>Any Pizza</span> i want to get only "Any Pizza" string

Comment: @naeemshah1, did you try it?  It worked as you asked, `lines` will be `{ "Any Pizza" }` in that example.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that you are going to fix your `html elements`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;p&gt;LARGE&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Lamb&lt;/p&gt;");

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        List<HtmlNode> spanNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "p").ToList();

        foreach (HtmlNode node in spanNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
        }

    }
```

You need to use HTML Agility Pack.You can add reference like this.:

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

Comment: PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
Install-Package : File contains corrupted data.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  HtmlAgilityPack
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], FileFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: @naeemshah1 here check this link. You can download it from their too: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: but msbirthname its can't remove span tag like i have  <span style=line-height: 1.6em;>Any Pizza</span>   i want to get only "Any Pizza"  string

Comment: @naeemshah1 Policy of stack overflow is to ask one problem per question you asked how to take <p>text</p> I give you the answer. If you have another problem create new question and mark this as finish.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- the original string is always going to be in that specific format,
  and that
- you cannot add the HTMLAgilityPack,

here is a quick and dirty way of getting what you want:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Split original string on the 'separator' string.
        string originalString = "&lt;p&gt;LARGE&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Lamb;<br>;li;ul;&nbsp;";
        string[] sSeparator = new string[] { "&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;" };
        string[] splitString = originalString.Split(sSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);

        // Prepare to filter the 'prefix' and 'postscript' strings
        string prefix = "&lt;p&gt;";
        string postfix = ";<br>;li;ul;&nbsp;";
        int prefixLength = prefix.Length;
        int postfixLength = postfix.Length;

        // Iterate over the split string and clean up
        string s = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < splitString.Length; i++)
        {
            s = splitString[i];
            if (s.Contains(prefix))
            {
                s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf(prefix), prefixLength);

            }
            if (s.Contains(postfix))
            {
                s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf(postfix), postfixLength);
            }

            splitString[i] = s;
            Console.WriteLine(splitString[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert &lt; &gt; etc. to HTML
String sResult = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sData);
// Remove HTML tags delimited by <>
String result = Regex.Replace(sResult, @"enter code here<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```